# Mantaflow smoke from Particles not working

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation

I am trying to set up my scene so that the Mantaflow smoke simulation will be generated from the particles generated by an Icosphere object. However, when I set that up, the simulation bakes but no smoke appears in the domain. When I set the source to the Icosphere's geometry, it works fine. Anyone have any idea how to fix this? I've tried everything I can think of (changing particle emission radius, particle size, simulation domain resolution etc)

Here is a link to the .blend file (sorry if this is not the way i am supposed to link .blends) https://www.mediafire.com/file/wknttvjs6yk188o/Smoke_particles_problem.blend/file